# What encoding does blob.download_as_string() return?

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I am downloading a file from Google Storage as a byte string, b64 encoding it, and using that as input into the Google Vision API.

```
storage_client = storage.Client(project=[PROJECT])
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket([BUCKET])
blob = bucket.blob([KEY])

content = blob.download_as_string()
b64content = base64.b64encode(content)

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.types.Image(content=b64content)
```

I am getting a bad image error using the b64content.  However, if I use the non base64 content, my call to the Vision API succeeds:

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
```

Does blob.download_as_string() return a byte string that is already base64 encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, it is not base64 encoded. Then why does it work with the non-encoded string?

Using the Python Client as you do, you don't need to encode the string, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python). You need to encode it if you post a Vision API request in JSON, like [this one](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request#json_request_format). This is why you get it working already without `base64.b64encode()`.